# ElasticSearch SubQuery

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

Is it possible to write query for ElasticSearch engine which would use data of one document to execute another query? Something like subquery in SQL.
For example you are gathering log documents and lets simplify the structure of Log Object to these fields:

```
{ orderId,
  processStep }
```

So I would like to find all documents that have processStep='Step 3' - this is easy and straightforward.
Lets say I get 100 results but now I want to check from this 100 results -> for that same orderId is there a document where processStep="Step 10 - End".
In the end I only want documents that don't have additional document for that order that marks the end of process -> processStep="Step 10 - End" , that means that these orders are still unfinished.

SQL equivalent would be:

```
SELECT * FROM Orders t1 WHERE t1.process_step='Step 3' AND NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM Orders t2 WHERE t2.process_step='Step 10 - End' AND **t2.ORDER_ID = t1.ORDER_ID**
)
```

Can this be achieved trough query? The only idea I found is to leverage Logstash to read documents and create new index with different structure which would for example have columns: orderId, isFinished but this looks to me like adding a lot of complexity for something that should not be that complex.

Additional info is that I can't change ES version which is 7.9.1